# jade -- Displaying foo if var does not equal any elements in an array

Tags: pug

I want to give users a 'subscribe' button if a variable (curBranch) is not equal to any elements in an array(user.subscribed), or an 'unsubscribe' button if it is not. I tried this:

```
- if (user != null)
  isSubscribed = false
  each subscription in user.subscribed
    - if (subscription === curBranch)
      isSubscribed = true
      form(action='/unsubscribe/#{curBranch}')
        button(type='submit') Unsubscribe

  - if (isSubscribed === false)
    form(action='/subscribe/#{curBranch}')
      button(type='submit') subscribe
```

The first part (before the line break) works perfectly. But jade seems to execute the third if-statement before the for loop has been completed.

Is there a way to make this run sequentially, alternatively, is there a different method I should be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do it using Array.indexOf() instead of a loop:

```
-if (user != null)
  -if (user.subscribed.indexOf(curBranch) > -1)
    form(action='/unsubscribe/#{curBranch}')
      button(type='submit') Unsubscribe
  -else
    form(action='/subscribe/#{curBranch}')
      button(type='submit') subscribe
```

Warning : indexOf IE support only [comes with IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility). If you're running jQuery, you can use `$.inArray(value, array)` or `_.contains(list, value)` using underscorejs.

Comment: It seems like if you use '- if' instead of 'if' you need to also use parens. Otherwise this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if user != null
isSubscribed = false
each subscription in user.subscribed
  if subscription == curBranch
    isSubscribed = true
    form(action='/unsubscribe/#{curBranch}')
      button(type='submit') Unsubscribe

if isSubscribed == false
  form(action='/subscribe/#{curBranch}')
    button(type='submit') subscribe
```